# 500 Internal Server Error - TS3 Module WHMCS

Tags: php, node.js, internal-server-error, whmcs, teamspeak

I am running a WHMCS website, we are going to offer Teamspeak 3 servers soon, we are using CPanel to host the website. Our current version of WHMCS is 7.0, it is licensed.

We are using a Windows VPS with a firewall that is currently turned off to host the TeamSpeak 3 servers. We have an API (using node.js) that is working with the module,

Everything works fine except one thing, when I enter the clientarea and goes to my TeamSpeak control panel I see buttons that says "start, stop, ban, settings" and all that, I can basicly turn on or off the teamspeak server from the control panel, but when I click any of those buttons my website just keeps loading and loading, the only way to stop it is to clear cookies. I forgot to mention that when I click e.g "stop" the teamspeak server actually stops, but the website keeps loading and it wont be solved until I clear cookies.
[Image on the Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROMtc.png)

I can't find anything in the logs. The API is running on "http://VPS-IP:3000"
And the port is open, I have no clue why this is happening. I also get this error if I wait for about 20 minutes after I've clicked on of these buttons.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@mysite.com to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Comment: I've looked into my error logs but they don't seem to log the problem

Comment: Go to Setup > General Settings > Other and enable "Display Errors" box.

Answer (score 0):

You really should look into your server error log file.
Check if it updated at all?
Take a look into /var/log directory and see if any general log activity exists?

This kind of problems always affects in the logs if not configured otherwise.

Regards.